# Sheets Formula : Can this formula be simplified?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, formula, divide

```
=((E2*G3)+(E3*G4)+(E4*G5)+(E5*G6)+(E6*G7)+(E7*G8)+(E8*G9)+(E9*G10)+(E10*G11)+(E11*G12))/(E2+E3+E4+E5+E6+E7+E8+E9+E10+E11+E12)
```

Very obvious what this is doing. It's multiplying one cell in column E by cell in G, one row below. Then, dividing this by the sum of column E down to the row that you are up to. Is there a better way to format the first part so it can be dragged down?

Cheers :)

Comment: Use SUMPRODUCT for the numerator and SUM for the denominator?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you..saved me some Googling!

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT for the numerator and SUM for the denominator? – BigBen 9 mins ago